# MySQL query to output free seats

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a theatre booking system in MySql and I have three tables:

```
Production (contains Title, BasicTicketPrice), 
Performance (PerformanceDate, PerformanceTime, Title) 
Booking (Email of person who booked, PerformanceDate, PerformanceTime, RowNumber).
```

I need to write a query which will display only one column: RowNumber from Booking but it needs to display ONLY the seats which are available on the PerformanceDate 2017-11-01 at PerformanceTime 19:00:00.

So far I tried:

```
SELECT RowNumber
FROM booking
WHERE Email IS NULL
```

Because each user can book a ticket using their email but the email is constrained by NOT NULL condition so I guess that is why my query doesn't work.

Any ideas on what I should try to make this work? I will be very grateful for any suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: using `Email IS NULL` when Email is defined as NOT NULL it's not very logical

Comment: I know, I realised that after I tried it but I am a beginner, I have a lot to learn and I need to familiarise myself with how queries work and everything. I also tried SELECT RowNumber FROM booking INNER JOIN performance per ON per.PerfDate = '2017-11-01' AND per.PerfTime = '19:00:00';

Comment: Your schema as shown is incorrect. There are no seats, only row numbers (unless this is supposed to be a single seat in which case your naming needs improving). You need a table that defines all seats from which to take, or else how are you going to know the difference, e.g., total - used? Also, some problems I see right away: production table seems irrelevant to your query as it does not matter what the title or ticket price are. Title should be normalized using the text once, and some title_id to refer to it, etc.

Comment: Hi Tonypdmtr the tables and their contents were given to me, I need to use the information as it is, I am not allowed to alter it. And yes, the RowNumber is the Seat.

Answer (score 0):

The following is sometimes called a "left excluding join", it is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that relates booking to performances via the performanceDate, but then excludes all rows that do have a match. This leaves you with just the booking rows that are available at that performance time.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM booking b
LEFT OUTER JOIN Performance p ON b.PerformanceDate = p.PerformanceDate
WHERE p.PerformanceDate IS NULL
```

**BUT**

I suspect that you are missing a table, which is simply a list of the seats. Without that the above query is (I think) likely to produce no rows, assuming that a row in a booking table is made only when a booking is received, **so the available seats probably don't exist in that table.**

An *inefficient* way to overcome the lack of a seats table would be to generate a distinct list of seats instead. e.g.

```
SELECT
      s.seat_number
FROM (select distinct row_number as seat_number from booking) s
LEFT JOIN booking b on s.seat_number = b.row_number
LEFT JOIN Performance p ON b.PerformanceDate = p.PerformanceDate
WHERE p.PerformanceDate IS NULL
```